# Last name misspelled on visa to south africa

Tags: visas, south-africa

My last name was misspelled on the visa, the embassy wrote `Zeeny` while on the first page of the passport it is written `Zeenny`, should I be concerned? I am flying out on monday and the consulate is closed for xmas.

Comment: Since the visa is presumably fixed in your passport, it is demonstrably a mistake on the part of the consulate and anybody who notices the spelling error should accept that.

Comment: We ended up hunting down the consul to fix the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We ended up having to go to the consul, he proceeded to cancel the first visa and issued a new one.